# How to get count items in foreign key Django?

Tags: python, django

I have two classes of models and I need to get the number of products from a single vendor

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    seo_name = models.SlugField()
    product_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)    


class Product(models.Model):
        vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, unique=False, blank=True, default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

How to calculate the count of products in the Vendor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [Django recipe: Add an auto-count field to your model](http://palewi.re/posts/2009/02/15/django-recipe-add-an-auto-count-field-to-your-foreignkey-model/)
 tutorial. It totally covers your question.

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks! Good Luck you too :)